# regexp exactly matches with similar word

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a pattern bellow:

```
var patt = /((name)|(names)*)/g;
```

and I have a string for match:

```
var word = "namesnames";
```

word is according to pattern logicly, but word.match(patt) return :

```
["name", "", "name", "", ""]
```

which is wrong!
i want "namesnames" result from match,
please help me.
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you used `(names)*`, meaning "names" 0 or more times, when you should have done `((name)(?:s))+`, meaning "name" or "names" 1 or more times.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want correctly, you can make it much simpler:

```
var patt = /(names?)+/g;
```

Comment: thanks very much.
I have another pattern too:
var patt = /((masoud)|(masoudrahimi)*)/g
and word = "masoudrahimimasoudrahimi";
please help me for true pattern for this too. thanks.